# React ChartJS -- Scale Bar Chart Vertically With More Datasets

Tags: javascript, chart.js, data-visualization, react-chartjs

I'm using React ChartJS to build a bar chart which currently looks like this[image: ReactJS Bar Chart]

The data that this is built on top of is dynamic -- that is, there can be many more industries (or fewer). I'd like to fix the bar width (say, at 30 pixels) and to have the chart grow taller according to how many datasets that I have. In other words, I don't care how tall the chart is, it should be a function of how many datasets that I have.

How would I accomplish this?

I'd share the code I've got already but it's pretty generic, can post it here if folks would find that useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you could wrap the `canvas` in a `div`.

```
<div id="chartWrapper">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

You can make use of the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) and compute the chart height in the `beforeRender` hook depending on the defined `data.barThickness` and the visible `datasets`.

```
plugins: [{
  beforeRender : chart => {        
    if (!chart.config.options.nonChartAreaHeight) {
      var yAxis = chart.scales.y;
      chart.config.options.nonChartAreaHeight = chart.height - (yAxis.bottom - yAxis.top);
    }      
    const labelCount = chart.data.labels.length;
    const datasetCount = chart.data.datasets.map((ds, i) => chart.getDatasetMeta(i)).filter(m => !m.hidden).length;
    const chartAreaHeight = labelCount * datasetCount * chart.data.barThickness * 1.2;
      document.getElementById("chartWrapper").style.height = (chartAreaHeight + chart.config.options.nonChartAreaHeight) + 'px';      
  }
}],
```

Then you also need to define `option.maintainAspectRatio: false` to prevent  `Chart.js` from resizing the `canvas`.

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [{
    beforeRender : chart => {        
      if (!chart.config.options.nonChartAreaHeight) {
        var yAxis = chart.scales.y;
        chart.config.options.nonChartAreaHeight = chart.height - (yAxis.bottom - yAxis.top);
      }      
      const labelCount = chart.data.labels.length;
      const datasetCount = chart.data.datasets.map((ds, i) => chart.getDatasetMeta(i)).filter(m => !m.hidden).length;
      const chartAreaHeight = labelCount * datasetCount * chart.data.barThickness * 1.2;
      document.getElementById("chartWrapper").style.height = (chartAreaHeight + chart.config.options.nonChartAreaHeight) + 'px';      
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 
    barThickness: 30, // change this to adapt the bar thickness
    datasets: [{          
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: [40, 50, 60, 80],
      backgroundColor: 'red'       
    },
    { 
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      data: [100, 90, 80, 70],
      backgroundColor: 'blue' 
    },
    {   
      label: 'Dataset 3',
      data: [60, 80, 70, 90],
      backgroundColor: 'green'  
    }]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  }
});
```

```css
div {  
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartWrapper">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```